# Flutter- Is it possible to make user rate our app with flutter, without closing or using launch_url and send user to the stores. from inside the app

Tags: flutter, dart, popup, rate

You know there are some pop-ups about "rate us" but I want that when I click a star it will give the star without close app or send me to the store page of my app.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrzpo.png)

Now I have with launch_url and send user to the store but does app store or play store allow that now in flutter?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_review did you try this one?

Comment: @OzanTaskiran it looks like it's workin with this package but does not appear any popup or something in that even if i get "onComplete: Successfully requested review flow" this message on my console